# Why is Pandas DataFrame Function 'isin()' taking so much time?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The 'ratings' DataFrame has two columns of interest: User-ID and Book-Rating.

I'm trying to make a histogram showing the amount of books read per user in this dataset. In other words, I'm looking to count Book-Ratings per User-ID. I'll include the dataset in case anyone wants to check it out.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

!wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/porterjenkins/cs180-intro-data-science/master/data/ratings_train.csv
ratings = pd.read_csv('ratings_train.csv')

# Remove Values where Ratings are Zero
ratings2 = ratings.loc[(ratings != 0).all(axis=1)]
# Sort by User
ratings2 = ratings2.sort_values(by=['User-ID'])
usersList = []
booksRead = []

for i in range(2000):
  numBooksRead = ratings2.isin([i]).sum()['User-ID']
  if numBooksRead != 0:
    usersList.append(i)
    booksRead.append(numBooksRead)

new_dict = {'User_ID':usersList,'booksRated':booksRead}
usersBooks = pd.DataFrame(new_dict)

usersBooks
```

The code works as is, but it took almost 5 minutes to complete. And this is the problem: the dataset has 823,000 values. So if it took me 5 minutes to sort through only the first 2000 numbers, I don't think it's feasible to go through all of the data.

I also should admit, I'm sure there's a better way to make a DataFrame than creating two lists, turning them into a dict, and then making that a DataFrame.

Mostly I just want to know how to go through all this data in a way that won't take all day.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: when you profile the code, is the most time taken in the for loop or the isin?

Comment: What do you mean profile the code? At the bottom of the screen it says something like: "Executing (15s)  -> Cell -> isin() -> isin() so I assumed it was the isin() function that was taking up most of the time.

Comment: your code has different lines; you have to run a profiler to find out which line eats the most time

Comment: Running the code on Google Colab right now, and there is a green arrow that sits on the line that has the isin() function. I assume that's telling me that's what it's working on at the moment.

Comment: It looks like you're doing a manual loop over 2000 numbers, then comparing your ratings to a single integer each time. Surely that will be slow.

Comment: that doesnt tell anything; look for `line_profiler` and check the amount of time consumed by each line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want a list of user IDs, with the count how often an ID appears in the dataframe. Use [`value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) for that:

```
ratings = pd.read_csv('ratings_train.csv')

# Remove Values where Ratings are Zero
ratings2 = ratings.loc[(ratings != 0).all(axis=1)]

In [74]: ratings2['User-ID'].value_counts()
Out[74]:
11676     6836
98391     4650
153662    1630
189835    1524
23902     1123
          ...
258717       1
242214       1
55947        1
256110       1
252621       1
Name: User-ID, Length: 21553, dtype: int64
```

The result is a Series, with the User-ID as index, and the value is number of books read (or rather, number of books rated by that user).

---

Note: be aware that the result is heavily skewed: there are a few very active readers, but most will have rated very few books. As a result, your histogram will likely just show one bin.

Taking the log (or plotting with the x-axis on a log scale) may show a clearer histogram:

```
np.log(s).hist()
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like what I was really looking for was the .value_counts() method? Thank you!!

Comment: you're better off log transforming the axis than the data.  the plot will be easier to read

Answer (score 1):

First filter by column `Book-Rating` for remove `0` values and then count values by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with convert to `DataFrame`, loop here is not necessary:

```
ratings = pd.read_csv('ratings_train.csv')

ratings2 = ratings[ratings['Book-Rating'] != 0]

usersBooks = (ratings2['User-ID'].value_counts()
                                 .sort_index()
                                 .rename_axis('User_ID')
                                 .reset_index(name='booksRated'))

print (usersBooks)
       User_ID  booksRated
0            8           6
1           17           4
2           44           1
3           53           3
4           69           2
       ...         ...
21548   278773           3
21549   278782           2
21550   278843          17
21551   278851          10
21552   278854           4

[21553 rows x 2 columns]
```